# Gray out specific radio-set after specific answer in other radio-set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with two question:
1. What day you want to come
2. What time you want to come
When you answer in question 1 "I can't attend" question 2 should be grayed out. I found a lot of possible solutions, but not the one which could help me :( . Most were with a checkbox, and based on the checked option a radio button was disabled or not. However, this is what I have so far:

```
<fieldset>
                    <div>
                        ~(IF(CHARINDEX('VISIT_DAY',DATA_ERROR)>=0,'<label style="color:#CC0000; font-weight:bold; width:100% !important; padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important; text-align:left !important;">','<label style="color:black; font-weight:bold; width:100% !important; padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important; text-align:left !important;">'))~ Ja, ik ben graag bij dit evenement aanwezig. Mijn voorkeursdag is:<span style="color:#CC0000;display:inline !important;">*</span> ~(IF(CHARINDEX('VISIT_DAY',DATA_ERROR)>=0,'</label>','</label>'))~

                        <div style="clear:both;">
                        </div>

                        <div style="float:left !important; clear:none !important;color:black;">
                            <input type="radio" value="A" style="width: auto !important;" ~(IF(@VISIT_DAY='A','checked',''))~ name="VISIT_DAY" /> 21 maart 2017<br />
                            <input type="radio" value="B" style="width: auto !important;" ~(IF(@VISIT_DAY='B','checked',''))~ name="VISIT_DAY" /> 22 maart 2017<br />
                            <input type="radio" value="C" style="width: auto !important;" ~(IF(@VISIT_DAY='C','checked',''))~ name="VISIT_DAY" /> Ik kan niet aanwezig zijn<br />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        ~(IF(CHARINDEX('VISIT_TIME',DATA_ERROR)>=0,'<label style="color:#CC0000; font-weight:bold; width:100% !important; padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important; text-align:left !important;">','<label style="color:black; font-weight:bold; width:100% !important; padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important; text-align:left !important;">'))~ Ik zal komen binnen het volgende tijdsbestek:<span style="color:#CC0000;display:inline !important;">*</span> ~(IF(CHARINDEX('VISIT_TIME',DATA_ERROR)>=0,'</label>','</label>'))~

                        <div style="clear:both;">
                        </div>

                        <div style="float:left !important; clear:none !important;color:black;">
                            <input type="radio" value="A" style="width: auto !important;" ~(IF(@VISIT_TIME='A','checked',''))~ name="VISIT_TIME" /> 09.30 - 13.00<br />
                            <input type="radio" value="B" style="width: auto !important;" ~(IF(@VISIT_TIME='B','checked',''))~ name="VISIT_TIME" /> 13.00 - 16.30<br />
                            <input type="radio" value="C" style="width: auto !important;" ~(IF(@VISIT_TIME='C','checked',''))~ name="VISIT_TIME" /> 16.30 - 20.00
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

So, when option C is selected in question 1, question two should be grayed out/disabled. Thank you very much! so far. 
Eelco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a change event listener to your radio VISIT_DAY, if the selected value is C, then you disable VISIT_TIME, if not, you activate it.

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name="VISIT_DAY"]', function(e) { 
    var $input = $(this)
      , value = $input.val()
      , $timeInput = $('input[name="VISIT_TIME"]')
      ;
    $timeInput.prop('disabled', value === "C");
} );
```